# Laravel POST to external API getting 2 different errors

Tags: laravel, http, guzzle

I'm getting 2 different errors when I'm trying to POST my form data to to external API.

On laravel debug:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

On error log:

> cURL error 28: Failed to connect to [www.sample.com/api.php](http://www.sample.com/api.php) port 443: Connection timed out

Controller:

```
public function postPayment(Request $request)
         {
        $Amount = request('Amount');
        $PayorName = request('PayorName');
        $PayorEmail = request('PayorEmail');
        $ReturnURLOK = request('ReturnURLOK');
        $ReturnURLError = request('ReturnURLError');
        
        $post = HTTP::post("www.sample.com/api.php", [
          'Amount' => $Amount,
          'PayorName' => $PayorName,
          'PayorEmail' => $PayorEmail,
          'ReturnURLOK' => $ReturnURLOK,
          'ReturnURLError' => $ReturnURLError,
            ]);
    }
```

Route:

`Route::post('postpayment', 'App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController@postPayment');`

Why am I getting 2 different errors? can someone help?

Comment: How are you calling the `postpayment` route?

Comment: In my payment.blade.php ```<form action="{{ action('PaymentController@postPayment') }}" method="POST" align="center">
                      @csrf
                      @method('POST')

```

Comment: Are you defined from `web.php`? if yes, you need to add this route to csrf exception.

Comment: remove @method('POST') and try again

Comment: `@method('POST')` is not required, secondly add your code in the question itself, thirdly, tell more about the external api you are calling like headers is the content-type :application/json, have you passed the auth if required by the 3rd party api, there should be other errors as well, as timeout error can occur due to a number of reasons

Comment: Additionally, take a look at `php artisan route:list` and make sure other routes don't conflict with this one. Like a `Route::get('{any}')` sort of thing.